# запомнить необязательную группу в регулярном выражении

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Имеется ли возможность запомнить значение необязательно группы в регулярном выражении?

Пример, близкий к моему случаю:

Допустим, у меня имеется регулярное выражение

```
(?:ВАЗ 2666).*(3 литра|10 тонн)
```

и 3 предложения для проверки

```
Автомобиль марки ВАЗ 2666 потребляет 3 литра бензина
Автомобиль марки ВАЗ 2666 весит 10 тонн
Автомобиль марки ВАЗ 2666 - это просто мечта!
```

Что тут получается: обработчик находит первые два предложения и запоминает в них группы ("3 литра" и "10 тонн" в каждом)..
Что нужно: чтобы обрабочик искал и учитывал все предложения, где встречается "ВАЗ 2666" и если находит "3 литра" или "10 тонн", то запоминал в массив и их..
Пробовал: ставить ? в конце выражения, обработчик ищет нужные предложения, но пропускает и не запоминает "3 литра" и "10 тонн".

Заранее извиняюсь за сложное объяснение простого вопроса.

Comment: Вы в курсе, что в вашем выражении нет необязательной группы? Добавьте тот код, который используете, и объясните, как должен выглядеть конечный результат.

Comment: Просто мне необходимо, чтобы искал все предложения с текстом "ВАЗ 2666", а в предложениях, в которых содержится "3 литра" или "10 тонн", запоминал запоминал этот текст

Comment: А, попробуйте `/ВАЗ 2666(?:.*(3 литра|10 тонн))?/`

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что нужно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сразу замечу, что `(?:ВАЗ 2666)` = `ВАЗ 2666`. `ВАЗ 2666.*(3 литра|10 тонн)?` не сработает, так как `.*` сразу захватит весь текст до конца строки (это "жадный" шаблон) и не оставит текста для `(3 литра|10 тонн)?`, который найдет всего лишь пустую строку (да, ведь квантификатор `?` позволяет находить "пустое" совпадение).

Используйте

```
/ВАЗ 2666(?:.*(3 литра|10 тонн))?/
```

**Подробности**

- `ВАЗ 2666` - буквальная подстрока `ВАЗ 2666`
- `(?:` - начало необязательной (так как после неё стоит квантификатор `?`) незахватывающей (так как после скобки стоит `?:`, текст, найденный шаблонами в этой группе не будет помещён в отдельный буфер памяти) группы (квантификатор `?` "жадный", движок попробует найти все шаблоны в этой группе хотя бы 1 раз, а если не найдёт совпадения, то совпадение все равно будет возвращено, если были найдены предыдущие шаблоны)

  - `.*` - 0 и более любых символов кроме символа перехода на новую строку
  - `(3 литра|10 тонн)` - либо `3 литра`, либо `10 тонн` (эта группа обязательная, т.е. если этот текст есть, он будет помещён в буфер первой захватывающей подмаски)
- `)?` - конец необязательной группы.

**[Демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/KQIDd6/1)**

Comment: `?:` - Это необязательная или незапоминаемая группа? Необязательная это разве не `)?`?

Comment: @Grundy Она там и такая и такая, `(?:...)?`.

Comment: Да это я что-то пропустил. Просто в описании выглядит так, будто это именно к `(?:` относится

Comment: @Grundy Описание просто так громоздко смотрится...

Comment: Ага, длинновато